# Microsoft Access: Change single column value in single row from form

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Access newbie here, I am updating an old Access database. I need a query or macro that updates the column "Quality Reviewer" to an assigned person based on what "department"  the user fills in.  I have the If then statement figured out but i can't seem to change a single value in the table.  This is all coming from a form that has the row already selected from the IDNJ column.

```
    SELECT [Job Log].IDJN, [Job Log].[Responsible Party], [Job Log].[Quality Reviewer], [Job Log].DepartmentID_FK
    FROM [Job Log]
    WHERE ((([Job Log].IDJN)=[Forms]![Job Log]![IDJN]));
```

This brings up a table where IDNJ is the ID number for the job. so, 4 columns and one row.  I need to update the "Quality Reviewer" to someone's initials "ABC"

I tried an update query but i could either update all records or none at all.  I think this might have to do with the other three fields are required and nothing can be done to the record till they are fulfilled.  But they are filled the update query just doesn't load the answers or something.

```
 UPDATE DISTINCTROW [Job Log] SET [Job Log].[Quality Reviewer] = "ABC"
 WHERE ((([Job Log].[Quality Reviewer])="[IDJN]=" & [IDJN]));
```

^That is the update query that doesn't work.

Comment: Don't use DISTINCTROW. The WHERE clause is not correct syntax. Reference to [Quality Reviewer] should not be there. It should be same as the SELECT criteria.

Comment: But if you already have the record displayed on form, UPDATE action SQL is not needed. Simply `Me![Quality Reviewer] = "ABC"`.

Comment: Where in the Query do I insert the  "Me!..." code?

Comment: Not in query, VBA behind form. Real trick is figuring out what event to put code in - perhaps AfterUpdate for "department" control.

Comment: Ok, that code works. but I need the action to occur after a certain button press.  The button is functional and filters who an email goes to.  Is there a way to but this thing of code behind a macro?  for context the button says that this job is ready for a review, so the button assigns a reviewer (a set person depending on the department and emails them)  there is an already functional form for the reviewer to see how many reviews they have  due.

Comment: Figured it out,  I just had a macro open another form then have the form immediately closed.  this macro is in the appropriate area in the If/else function that is behind a button press.  Thanks for all the help June7!